# Correct usage of Rewriterule using a specific domain

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, browser

im trying to build a redirect using .htaccess .

I have to domains, a german one called "german.de" and an english one called "english.com"
Now I want to forward some links to certain youtube videos. To be more specific I want the same links on both domains , e.g.:

german.de/catvideo

english.com/catvideo

for the german one I have working rules like:

```
Redirect 302 /catvideo http://youtube.com/watch?catsarecoolADDAD
```

for the english one i tried to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?english\.com
RewriteRule "^/catvideo$" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?catsarecoolADDAD" [R=301,L]
```

But it does not seem to work, if I change it to :

```
RewriteRule "^$" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?catsarecoolADDAD" [R=301,L]
```

it correctly redirects "english.com" to the above youtube link. Please help me.

Comment: When configured in .htaccess context, the path RewriteRule works on never starts with a slash (that has been stripped at that point already.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is solved, I did the redirects on the apache2 webserver, /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName german.de
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  Redirect /catvideo https://www.youtube.com/watch?catsarecoolADDAD
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName english.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  Redirect /catvideo https://www.youtube.com/watch?catsarecool1234
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash

```
RewriteRule "^catvideo$" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?catsarecoolADDAD" [R=301,L]
```